# Python listas sequência

Tags: python, lista

Tenho uma lista de referência com valores repetidos ex:. `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`.

Estou tentando criar uma outra lista que crie uma sequência crescente a partir do primeiro conjunto de dados, reiniciando a contagem quando aparecer outro valor.

Explicando melhor: na lista de referência há duas vezes o valor `1` (na posição 0 e 1), então na lista final quero que apareça, os valores 1 e 2 nestas mesmas posições; quando mudar o número da lista de referência, a contagem deve recomeçar.

Portanto, o resultado deve ser `[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Estou usando o código abaixo:

```
lista_referencia= [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
localizador = 0
contador = 0
for i in lista_referencia:
    if i != lista_referencia[localizador - 1]:
        print(1)
    else:
        x = 2 + contador
        print( x, 'arrumar') # arrumar é onde não consigo por a sequência
        contador += 1
    localizador += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tentei entender seu código, mas me parece que está complicando à toa.

Basta fazer um *loop* e guardar uma referência ao elemento anterior. Quando o elemento atual for igual ao anterior, incremente o contador. Se for diferente, o contador volta para 1.

Vale lembrar que você não está gerando uma nova lista, está somente imprimindo os valores. Então crie esta lista e adicione as contagens nela:

```
lista_referencia= [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]

contagens = []
anterior = None # no início não tem anterior
contador = 1
for n in lista_referencia:
    if n == anterior: # elemento atual igual ao anterior, incrementa o contador
        contador += 1
    else: # mudou o número, reinicia o contador
        contador = 1
    # adiciona o contador na lista
    contagens.append(contador)
    # atualiza o anterior
    anterior = n

print(contagens) # [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

Talvez seja meio exagero para este caso, mas enfim, também é possível usar o [módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import groupby, count, chain

def nums(items): # obtém os números de 1 até o tamanho do iterável
    return [ i for i, _ in zip(count(1), items) ]

lista_referencia= [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
contagens = list(chain.from_iterable(nums(run) for _, run in groupby(lista_referencia)))
print(contagens) # [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Basicamente, `groupby` agrupa os elementos consecutivos iguais. Depois, a função `nums` obtém uma lista de 1 até a quantidade de números em cada grupo, então geramos uma lista para as repetições de 1, outra para as repetições de 2, etc.

E por fim, `chain.from_iterable` cria um único iterável a partir de todas essas listas, e eu coloco tudo em uma única lista.

Como eu disse, meio exagerado, já que a primeira opção me parece mais simples (de fazer e de entender). Mas fica aí como curiosidade.

---

Obs: o que acontece se tivermos uma lista como `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1]`? Repare que há duas sequências de `1`, então o resultado com os códigos acima será `[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]` - terminando com `1, 2`, pois cada sequência de `1` é contada separadamente.

Já a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/493518/112052) (que foi apagada) resulta em `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, pois ela considera a contagem total de `1`, mesmo que não estejam todos consecutivos.

Claro que se estes casos não ocorrem, aí tanto faz.

Comment: Bem mais simples e resolveu 100%. Muito obrigado.